# Ignore Assigned Type to Generate a Type From a Literal Value

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm not sure this is possible with TypeScript, but I want define a new type from a object literal that will 'narrow' the object literal's existing type to what is actually present on the object.

**Here's what I want.**

```
type BigOptionalObject = {
  prop1?: string
  prop2?: string
  prop3?: string
};

// Typing this helps me to make sure I'm creating the object 
// as expected when it's used elsewhere by functions requiring BigOptionalObject.
// Yes, I could just not type this and it would solve all of my problems and still
// be accepted in functions that expect BigOptionalObject... but I want TS to be
// helping me/other devs when working directly with this object.
const MyObject: BigOptionalObject = {
  prop1: 'hi'
};

// But I want to create type to be { prop1: 'hi' } or { prop1: string }... 
// but it is BigOptionalObject, which makes sense because TS is reading the type assigned to it.
type TypeOfMyObject = typeof MyObject;
```

**I tried this:**

```
const MyObject: BigOptionalObject = {
  prop1: 'hi'
} as const;

// Still BigOptionalObject
type TypeOfMyObject = typeof MyObject;
```

**And this:**

```
const MyObject = {
  prop1: 'hi'
} as BigOptionalObject;

// No longer BigOptionalObject! But it is the shaped defined by BigOptionalObject.
type TypeOfMyObject = typeof MyObject;
```

Again, I'm not sure this feature exits. It would be something like `TypeOfVariable<MyObject>` or `typeof variable MyObject` that calculates the type of the actual variable while ignoring the existing assigned type of the variable.

Obviously TypeScript can do this (and does), so it's just some way to override the default behavior to use the assigned type when using `typeof`.

**This is valid TypeScript:**

```
const MyObject = {
  prop1: 'hi'
};

// The type here is { prop1: string }.
type TypeOfMyObject = typeof MyObject;
```

Comment: ① Please fix any code typos so this is a [mre]. ② Are you just looking for the `satisfies` operator as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Wzkn1w)?  If so I could answer (or more likely point to an existing question). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz you sir, are a hero. I had read about satisfies a while ago, but we just upgraded our project to TS 4.9 a couple months ago and I forgot about it.

fwiw, I asked this question to ChatGPT-4 in many different variations and it told me over and over it could not be done. So I guess you can feel confident you're still smarter than the latest AI. :)